# framework not found GoogleMapsCore Error

Tags: xcode, google-maps, frameworks

I'm using cocoapods in my project and I have googlemaps(2.5.0) and googleplaces(2.5.0) in my podfile(which I've installed with 'pod install').

However, I'm getting this error when I try to build:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleMapsCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've changed 'Build Active Architecture Only' to NO in my Build Settings. I'm also in my project.xcworkspace NOT my project.xcodeproj file. I've even tried changing my valid architectures but none of this is working.

It might be helpful to note that, inside my workspace Project Navigator, for some reason I have my project.xcodeproj file in red. project.xcodeproj is usually never there let alone red.

Comment: Did u manage to solve this?

Comment: sadly, no. If you have any suggestions please send them over because I'm still racking my brain

Comment: Did you get any success? Facing same issue

Comment: @ShrutiThombre Yes. check the below solution.

Comment: @king_sammm Below solution didn't work for me, actually the problem is with my pod, I am using `pod 'Bolts'` which was causing issue along with `pod 'GoogleMaps'`.. once i have removed `pod 'Bolts'` everything works fine

Comment: @king_sammm you can check my question and answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/52720281/5620447 and feel to accept it, Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Finally a solution:

```
pod deintegrate 
pod install
```

I had to reclone my Git project(because I had tried too many solutions to backtrack through new warnings and errors) then I just did the above commands in terminal.

Comment: Not Working - i am using this within customFramework it won't delete from this.

Answer (score 3):

Though @Sam King's solution worked for me, I considered it as a hard fix without knowing the actual issue. 
The issue for my case was, I had accidentally deleted the GoogleMapsCore framework(Might be from 'Manage System Storage').

So, I just checked out an older version of my app and the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Ionic Framework,

Remove googlemap plugin and install again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem after deleting GoogleMapsCore by mistake. and here's what worked for me:

From my project podfile , commented out the pods related to google maps, in my case
//rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

// pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

// pod 'GoogleMaps'

// pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

1. cd ios && pod install , to remove the pods i commented out
2. then i uncommented the pods i have commented earlier in step 1
3. cd ios && pod install to install the pods again
4. ran a clean build on xcode and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but in my case I want to remove GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces.

After removing 'GoogleMaps' and 'GooglePlaces' from podfile, I got similar errors.

I have solved the problem in this way.

At `Project -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags`

[image]

Select these frameworks and delete them. By doing this, your framework will be completely removed and you can build the project successfully. Hope this will help someone want to remove the frameworks integrated through pods.

Answer (score 0):

Remove googlemap related plugin and install again. It worked for me.

Please dont do deintegrate pod, if you do all libraries get install as new, that some how some libraries would not support your platform.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to install the google places along with the GoogleMaps pod it will definitely work

Try this

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

if it doesn't work then open the terminal and do this below steps for your project

```
pod deintegrate 

pod install
```

then

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to remove the pod files using this command while in ios folder:

```
pod deintegrate
```

then run

```
pod install
```

to install pods.

it worked for me.