# Bitrise : GoogleMaps framework not found issue

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xcode9.2, bitrise

I am using `Bitrise` to generate build and upload it to AppStore. There were no errors when i run app on device or generate build and upload to AppStore via Xcode no problem occurred, but when i tried to do the same process via `Bitrise` it fails saying

> ❌  ld: framework not found GoogleMaps
>   ❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       Ld /Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**-dieoklyyfvjmlsccijdlwfgpxbsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/**/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/**.build/Staging-iphoneos/Deliverr.build/Objects-normal/armv7/** normal armv7
>   (1 failure)

Here is project setting

[image: project setting]

I have tried by changing `Architecture` setting as well

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution :

> I am using `pod 'Bolts'` which was causing issue along with `pod 'GoogleMaps'` , once i removed pod 'Bolts' everything works fine

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution and thanks for sharing!