# Error: Framework not found googlemapscore

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

The build is worked before a day but not working now. I'm getting this error when I try to build in IOS:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleMapsCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [framework not found GoogleMapsCore Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014488/framework-not-found-googlemapscore-error)

Comment: NO that answer doesn't work for me